# Excel: IF statement with ISBLANK over a range

Tags: excel

I have a two columns, one with prices and one with the word "yes" or blank.

With this I also have a simple sum for my total cost.  I am looking to create an expression that IF the value in column C is yes (or inversely if it is blank), to subtract its corresponding price in column B from the total to come up with the amount left over still.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you want to sum the blanks and then minus the "yes"s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to sum the blanks and then minus the "yes"s from that:

```
=SUMIFS($B:$B, $C:$C, "")-SUMIFS($B:$B, $C:$C, "yes")
```